# Hiding few steps in an already existing installer

Tags: postgresql, installation, batch-file

Is there a way to hide few steps during an installation of an already existing installer? Like, hide the steps for the inputting of username or password? I want to hide these steps during the installation and run a batch file or script to set the default username or password instead.

Is there a possible way for this? How can I do this?

For example, installing postgreSQL, I'd like to hide the steps/windows for the username/password input, and run a batch file to set the username and password.

*PS: I am not the author of the installer, I just want to modify it that way, if it is possible.*

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using (EnterpriseDB) One Click Installer or pgInstaller ?

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL you need to install in that way ?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.0.4 (x64) version and its an EnterpriseDB installer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found an answer for my problem. It is performing an unattended installation where a user interaction is not needed anymore. Installation can be done in the command line where parameters can just be added (a config file can also be used for these parameters).

See the following links:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/8.4/instguide/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Installation_Guide-15.htm#P889_74430

For command line options reference:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/8.4/instguide/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Installation_Guide-17.htm#P1062_89370

*Although this installation process only displays a progress bar, my problem is already solved since no user interaction is already needed. :)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to just hide particular one step from installer. Moreover AFAIK One Click Installer is only closed source, so you can't change its behaviour. However there are two alternative ways:

- show visually that step, but with other default values, so user can simply click next
- run installer in non-interactive mode (`--mode unattended`)

First of all check available options with [Installation Guide](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide) and:

```
cmd>postgresql-9.0.4-1-windows_x64.exe --help
```

For example you can adjust `--superaccount MyCustomizedUser --superpassword 12345` with such result (default is postgres and blank password):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz! I chose the non-interactive mode. Although, it won't display all other steps in the installation anymore, only the progress bar, but the user input for password/username is not needed anymore. :)